# How to move edge of cube to global (0, 0, 0)

Tags: objects

When the Cube is created it is at its center at global (0, 0, 0). I do however want to move all dimensions so that edges are at (0, 0, 0).
When moving the Object, it seems like there is no snap options to snap it.

Comment: you can snap to grid (it's called Increment in the Snap To panel)

Answer (score 6):

So I found that the following works:

- Switch to *edit* mode
- Select Vertex/Edge you want to use
- Shift + S and select "Cursor to Selected"
- Switch to *object* mode
- In "Object/Set Origin" menu select "Origin to 3D Cursor"
- Then when using "Move" enable snapping with "Shift + Tab". Then snapping the Edge to global (0,0,0) works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Blender's [Snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) is enabled or disabled by clicking the magnet icon in the header:

[image: Header menus with snapping button highlighted].

There's a shortcut to toggle this on or off: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd>

As the manual page says, there are many snapping modes.  You select the mode from the menu to the right of the magnet icon:

[image: Snapping mode menu]

Because the cube has unit dimensions, you can use *Increment* mode and turn on "Absolute Grid Snap" in the menu.  Then when you move the cube it will move in grid size steps.  If you zoom in you get a finer grid and more control.